# fstack-protector in cordova ionic3

Tags: sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3, cordova-3

Can anyone help me with **-fstack-protector** enabling for Cordova Ionic3, Angular4- android based mobile application. Elf built without Stack Protection is vulnerable and I would like to fix the same in mobile app.

I am using sqllite for offline storage. Enabling this option can have a impact on offline storage or performance? Please help. Please suggest how to enable the same. Thanks.